# Using CodeIgniter model outside of controller, insert fails until at least one query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CI project I want to use with a 'raw' HTTP request, and I want to load the model and reuse that logic.  That all sort of works, but I'm having trouble with inserting data.

I have one table, let's just call it 'foo' with one column 'bar' of varchar(4096).

I cannot insert data in to 'foo' until I query the database at least once, it doesn't matter what table.

```
include '../external.php';
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('session');
$CI->load->database();
```

where 'external.php' is basically a copy of index.php modified to suppress output.

If I do:

```
    $data = array("bar" => $foo);
    $this->db->insert (self::TABLE, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
```

In my model I get back:

```
        INSERT INTO `foo` (`bar`) VALUES ('')
```

which is clearly not right.

Any idea why doing a query first (for anything, for instance you can do a $this->db->count_all('unrelated_table'); and then the INSERT above has a value in the 'bar' column.

Comment: how do you get this one ' INSERT INTO `foo` (`bar`) VALUES ('')'? another one It's very difficult to get what you want to say.

Comment: The column names don't matter, I've tried in multiple tables with different names.  `bar` is the column name in this case, and the value it tries to insert is blank.

Comment: is array contain values?

Comment: how do you get to the $foo?

Comment: Yes, if I do a print_r($data) the array has all the values I expect, and of the datatype I want.

Comment: It's definitely a CodeIgniter bug or issue, because if I add a count_all on any table then the insert works correctly.  If I do not then the insert tries to put in empty values.